# javax.servlet.error.exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceImports

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror, helios

I have problem to run my apps using Tomcat 7. I got this error:

> javax.servlet.error.exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceImports

But when I run using Tomcat 8, it works fine. I need to use Tomcat 7 because I want to run the Tomcat from Eclipse Helios, and Eclipse Helios does not support Tomcat 8.

I do not know how to fix this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: are you using maven for dependency management?

Comment: What's the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: yes @KrishnaKuntala i am using maven

Comment: heres the error:

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/icars] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceImports] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceImports
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:1